# Mozilla(Firefox) , Marker , Multiple SVGs

Tags: firefox, svg, d3.js, marker

I've enbedded d3's force directed graph layout  into extjs tabs so that each time a new tab gets added a new graph svg gets generated.
No Problemo so far.

Now I intended to turn the graph into a directed one (by adding a marker and tell the lines to use it)

Each generated svg elements is following this pattern:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">

<defs><marker id="end-arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="6" markerWidth="3"     markerHeight="3" orient="auto"><path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" fill="#ccc"></path></marker>
</defs>

<g transform="translate(4,0) scale(1)"><line class="link" sig="30.84" style="stroke-width: 3;" x1="538" y1="347" x2="409" y2="467" marker-end="url(#end-arrow)"></line>
...
</g>
</svg>
```

With Crome everything works just fine.
So I arrived at the concusion that the structur and 
the way I generate the svgs should be more or less correct.

But with Firefox the Markers will only show for the first svg. (the first tab)
All other svgs won't show any Arrowheads.

"Inspect Elements" tells me the Markers are there and that the lines are refering to them.

And this is where I'm running out of Ideas where or what to look for. :(

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so we can see the code? Also are you sure you don't have duplicate id attributes?

Comment: yeah,duplicate ids where my first first thought. Especially since all markers ID ="end-arrow".   but since they are are unique within their svg and because another browser displays them proper without problems I doubt that it is an ID thing. But maybe I'm missing something obvious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple non-distinct IDs within the same html or svg document. [This is invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#id), different UAs respond differently but as you're not allowed to do this, it doesn't really matter that they are inconsistent.